# How can I determine the max scroll position in different browsers with different line-height and/or padding?

Tags: javascript, css

Is there a way to determine the max scroll position for every browser, without actually scrolling to the end and reading this position?

Taken a container div with a fixed height and overflow. Several div elements in the container whose  sum of heights is bigger then the height of the container.

There is a max scroll position (y) which I thought is simply the container-height minus the total items-height. This seems to be true until the `line-height` of the container is larger then the `height` of the items. If this is the case, it seems that every browser determines the max scroll position differently.

With padding it got even worse, some browsers add the top padding, some browsers add both top and bottom padding.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/woomla/UMJ4n) for example. Play around with the container line-height and the div.item height.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I only have the ability to test in a handful of browsers, but I think what you are looking for is:

```
elm.scrollHeight - elm.clientHeight
```

Shown in an updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UMJ4n/27/).

Comment: Beware: `elm.clientHeight` is not part of any W3C specification. See [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.clientHeight?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Felement.clientHeight).

Comment: I've discovered Firefox as of 28 supports `elm.scrollTopMax` which returns the same number as `elm.scrollHeight - elm.clientHeight` though it's nowhere documented on MDN and not supported in other browsers.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this [How to find the HTML element Scrollable Height and width using JQuery ?](http://jqfaq.com/how-to-find-the-html-element-scrollable-height-and-width-using-jquery/), this shows how to get the scrollable height and width,
and there is some related posts regarding element scroll [how to check if the scrollbars are currently visible?](http://jqfaq.com/how-to-check-if-the-scrollbars-are-currently-visible/) and [how to determine if the vertical and horizontal scrollbars reaches the edges?](http://jqfaq.com/how-to-determine-if-the-vertical-and-horizontal-scrollbars-reaches-the-edges/).
and there are more FAQs available and i hope this will help you !.